# Magento 1.9.2.4 404 with custom controller

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404

I've got module: local/Zzepish/Example.
etc/config.xml:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <example>
            <class>Zzepish_Example_Model</class>
        </example>
    </models>

    <helpers>
        <example>
            <class>Zzepish_Example_Helper</class>
        </example>
    </helpers>

    <models>
        <example>
            <class>Zzepish_Example_Model</class>
        </example>
    </models>

    <blocks>
        <example>
            <class>Zzepish_Example_Block</class>
        </example>
    </blocks>
</global>

<frontend>
    <routers>
        <example>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Zzepish_Example</module>
                <frontName>example</frontName>
            </args>
        </example>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

app/etc/modules/Zzepish_Example.xml

```
<modules>
    <Zzepish_MyModule>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends />
    </Zzepish_MyModule>
</modules>
```

controller in Zzepish/Example/controllers/IndexController.php :

```
class Zzepish_Example_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'Hello!';
    }
}
```

But, when i go to my_website/example , my_website/example/index/index it redirects me to 404.

Answer (score 0):

problem is in 
app/etc/modules/Zzepish_Example.xml update with following

```
<modules>
    <Zzepish_Example>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends />
    </Zzepish_Example>
</modules>
```